# How to bypass the restart required command in the Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

A little bit of context in this problem. My personal computer is currently unusable. That's why I am trying to continue my side project elsewhere. I found a decent internet cafe nearby. However I ran into some issue.

[image: screenshot]

The problem here is that since I am on an Internet Cafe if I restart the computer that I am using all the newly downloaded files will disappear.

Due to the security arrangements in place, even if I successfully restart the computer the visual studio will be lost upon reboot.

Can you come up with a creative solution for this?

Any contribution will be appreciated no matter how small.

The goal here is to be able to launch the visual studio without restarting the computer.

Comment: No, you need to restart. However if you are not working with .NET Framework 4.x, then you can use VS Code instead.

Comment: @DavidG I am developing some windows form application therefore switching to VS code is not ideal for me.

Comment: @DavidG As I have stated earlier if I restart, everything will go down the drain and I have to start all over again. Making that effort pointless and a waste of time.

Comment: Install VS in a virtual machine. That way you can restart the VM whenever you want to. Ofc, if there is no VM host installed you can probably not install one, since that likely also require a reboot.

Comment: You could possibly use some cloud based virtual machine or development environment provider, but chances are that it will take a longer time to setup than it would take to fix whatever problem you have with your PC.